# Extracting Data from a dataset returned from a web service

Tags: .net, web-services, soap, wsdl

Has anyone a source of the query language used to extract data returned from a web service.

I wrote a web service returns a dataset,

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public DataSet GetData()
    {
        AWDS ds = new AWDS();//AWDS is my dataset class name
        SalesPersonTableAdapter ta = new SalesPersonTableAdapter();
        ta.Fill(ds.SalesPerson);
        return ds;
    }
}
```

I used this query I found in a resource

```
<Query>
<Method Namespace="http://tempuri.org/" Name="GetData">
</Method>
<SoapAction>http://tempuri.org/GetData</SoapAction>
</Query>
```

"whats this query language name"

but I get the schema of the data set(my tables columns shown as records).

I want to learn more how to get the the schema of a certain table.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to the URL for your web service and add ?wsdl to the end of it.

Find **wsdl:definitions** and look at the **targetNamespace** attribute. This value is what the **Method**'s **Namespace** attribute should be set to in your query.

Find the **wsdl:operation** element whose **name** attribute is equal to the method you want to use and look at the **soap:operation** below it. Look at the value of the **soapAction** attribute. This value is what you will place in the **SoapAction** element in your query.

Also, see the following references:

[Reporting Services: Using XML and Web Service Data Sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964129%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

[XML Query Syntax for Specifying XML Report Data (SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345251.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Please try to be more clear about what you're asking. I have no idea what this "query" XML is that you posted. It's not a query language at all.

Also, you should avoid returning DataSet from a web service. It doesn't interoperate with non .NET platforms, and sometimes not with .NET, either.

---

I found some resources on xmlDP on MSDN. See [xmldp query syntax](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/?Query=xmldp+query+syntax).

I hope that helps.

Comment: Ok, it's a query language named xmlDP used to sail through wxl returned from a web service, and i'm encountering a lack of resources about